# How do I open the gate in Fungi Forest near warp point 5?

Tags: donkey-kong-64

In Fungi Forest there is a metal gate near warp point 5. It is guarded by an enemy with a spiked club and has a blue banana behind it. Punching it with Funky Kong has no effect.

How do I open this gate in Fungi Forest?

[image: gate in fungi forest]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Grape Switch above the door. Climb up the nearby mushroom and hit the switch with Lanky Kong's Grape Shooter to open the gate.